# redirect page during execute long query

Tags: php

i execute long query and take long time,
 i want to redirect to another page during that process and continue executing my problem here when i redirect to another page the query stop executing...
for example :

```
$emails = array(1, 2, and so on to 100k for example);
```

i want to send to $emails and redirect during sending to another page and tell me how much email send

and i try to search the problem and i cant find the solution or i searching with wrong way

Comment: uses exec to call another page\script to run the job in the background `exec(php send_email.php);`

Comment: thanks very much for your comment,
can you till me the way or the code to do this :)

Comment: code is as above: `exec(php send_email.php);`  fullpath to php\file may be required

Comment: my brother this is right way ??
exec($obj->send_message($user_id, $row, $subject, $message));
redirect('home');

Comment: can i add function as parameter to execute and the redirect..

Comment: exec runs a program, it does not call a function. you need to put your function calls inside the file you run via exec

Comment: i use codeigniter, is this right way  
exec('sending/index/'.$user_id.'/'.$row.'/'.$subject.'/'.$message);

Comment: i want to use var value in the function in sending.php

Answer (score 1):

You're problem is that php is executes line-by line. So if you redirect in the middle of a process the rest will not execute.

You can write a scirpt that sends the emails. Put that into a php file. Than open that file with curl, be sure to add a short timeout(1sec for example)

To keep track of the emails actually sent you will have to insert those into a db, or create some file that contains the data you need. Even though you will still have to wait for the total number until all the emails are sent.

Answer (score 0):

actually,php execute line by line,and u can't redirect during the process,as this will not continue the process of sending emails

best way to solve ur problem is to use cron jobs as follow:

1. build the page that will send the emails
2. build a new cron job to be performed every x time
3. in php code,u can add a snippet that will make the previous file to be performed via cron job when u click the sending button

ex:

```
if(isset($_POST)){

//code to make a new file containing sending process

}
```

Comment: mr.mohammed can u add the corn code that will sending emails automatically in background while i can browse any other page .